# Does my PC generate a raw audio data file when I speak into the microphone?

Tags: r, audio, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I'm going to try my hand at writing a *very* basic speech recognition algorithm (speech to text) via the R statistical programming language.

The plan is to build a training dataset by recording spoken word samples into my PC's microphone, and then attempt to match spoken phrases with the recorded word samples in the training data using a suitable algorithm (such as neural networks or hidden Markov model). However in order to do this I first need to translate sound files into raw data.

**Does my PC generate an audio data file when I speak into microphone?** By audio data file I mean, for example, a text file containing measurements of the recorded sound waves (frequency, amplitude, etc.) per unit of time (milliseconds?). If so, how do I access the file? If not, are there applications that can convert audio files into data?

Comment: You can simply use http://www.rforge.net/audio/

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev Great, thank you Nikolay, that's what I was looking for.